# Using the comparable interface to compare two object

Tags: java, comparable

I am trying to use the comparable interface so that I can use the searching algorithms in the Collection API on a list of `Param<?,?>` object. I don't know how to implement `compareTo` method correctly since its fields are not necessary numerical.  How could I implement this method so that the Collections API algorithms work correctly with a collection of this object?

```
public final class Param <K,V> implements Comparable<Param<K,V>>{

private final K key;
private final V value;

public Param (K key, V value)
{
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) 
{
    if(obj == null)
        return false;

    if (!obj.getClass().getName().equals(this.getClass().getName()))
        return false;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Param<K, V> param = (Param<K, V>)obj;
    if (this.getKey ().equals(param.getKey()) && this.getValue().equals(param.getValue()))
        return true;

    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() 
{
    int hash = 5;

    hash += this.key.hashCode();
    hash += this.value.hashCode();
    return hash;
}


public int compareTo(Param <K,V> o)
{
    if (this.hashCode() == o.hashCode())
        return 0;
    return -1;
}
}
```

Comment: You can't implement a proper comparison here without knowing how to compare `K` and `V`.  Perhaps you should restrict `K` and `V` to be `Comparable` themselves?

Comment: Let's say you have two random Param objects. How would you compare them? You need to specify your problem more clearly.

Comment: There's no need to compare Class objects by name. They are unique, so if you want to know if `obj` and `this` have the same type, just do `obj.getClass() == this.getClass()`.

Comment: You violate the contract of Comparable.  If `a` and `b` are distinct `Param` instances, then both `a.compareTo(b)` and `b.compareTo(a)` return `-1`, which is an inconsistent ordering function.  If you need to implement `Comparable` you must provide a consistent ordering.